# OpenLayers browser related changelog

Tags: openlayers-3

For the time being the latest stable release of [OpenLayers](http://openlayers.org) is *v3.18.2* and of course it doesn't support old browsers.
But I noticed that many examples in *v3.2.1* are supported by old webkit.
What are the new features that make it unsupported?
For instance, is the [snap](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/examples/snap.html) one of these features?

- [Examples v3.2.1](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/);
- [Examples v3.18.2](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.18.2/examples/).

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of old webkit?

Comment: For instance my first-generation iPad or the Qt4 webkit. They both are not able to show examples in v3.18.2 but only the examples in v3.2.1. Unlikely I can't download old versions of Chrome so I can't be more precise.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the maximum canvas size?